# How to create a jar file from xsd

Tags: java, jar, xsd

*How to create a `jar` file containing class files generated from a given `xsd` file*? 
Do we need to create all the java files from `xsd` and then need to compile and create a `jar`?
 
Or, other solutions are there.

Can anyone please explain the process?

Comment: why do you need to create java archive for xsd which is static file? what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is our project related. We have to create jar file and need to deliver it.

Comment: In C#.NET we use xsd files to generate classes, this might be what the starter want to accomplice.

Comment: I am almost sure you are doing something wrong after having read your question but the direct answer is here:jar is just an archiver, you can do with jar everything you can do with zip, so _jar -c file.jar file.xsd_ will create a jar with a single xsd file in it

Comment: Ok.. so we need to create java files first and the need to make the jar files.

Comment: @bobah, the command you posted will not create a file but rather send the output to the STDOUT. Read the 5th line of the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html.

Comment: @aviad - true, corrected command line: _jar cf file.jar file.xsd_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are trying create Java classes from XSD for futher XML<->POJO mapping. Am I right?

If so - it depends on mapping lib that you use. Assume that you are using JAXB 2. The easiest way is to use XJC Maven plugin like here : http://mojo.codehaus.org/xjc-maven-plugin/usage.html and Maven will package everything to JAR then.

Comment: So if you need to provide Java classes in JAR this is basically the way. Is it clear?

Comment: Link is dead, please post updated site, or maybe transcript the need information, at this point this "answer" is useless.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following steps if you are not using mavne to generate jar-

1. Copy your xsd to a folder.- eg Test.xsd
2. From the command prompt go to the folder and use the command-

   **xjc  Test.xsd**

or u can use  xjc -p --package name--

**xjc -p test Test.xsd**

This will create all your java files from the xsd, in a folder called generated(default) or test inside your working folder.

1. From the command prompt use -

   **javac generated/***

   This will create classes files of all the java files generated.
2. Lastly, from the command prompt, use

   **jar cvf test.jar generated/***

   This will create the jar with all the classes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your xsd file in some directory (call it resources for example)
2. In command line navigate to the directory where the resources dir is located.
3. Run `jar cf jar-file %input-file_name%`  (input-file-name is 'resources' in your case)

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

I believe there are more elegant ways to ship static content (which the xsd is) However, you do not want to disclose your goal so that is how you create the jar.

Good luck!